# Every morning I have no internet at around the same time

Tags: windows-10, internet-connection

I have finished installing my new PC, Windows 10.

Every morning, the ethernet can no longer connect. It seems to happen at around 7:51 ish every day (I think closer to 07:50:50).

Other devices (wireless) connect to the internet fine during this time.

Trouble shooting does not fix it - only a restart of the computer fixes the issue

Because it always happens at around the same time each day, I believed something was being trigged in task scheduler or similar. I have tried to disable everything in task scheduler, and this has not helped.

I have no other ideas

**EDIT**

It fails between 7:45 and 8:00 every day
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Update**

During this time, a ping to 8.8.8.8 fails. A ping to my local gateway, 192.168.1.254 also fails

I've also noted that usually the computer will not restart... I have to press and hold the power button

[image]

(Oddly, when I restart the computer, the `Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 10` does not exist). The next screen shows when everything is working

[image]

Motherboard: ASUS ROG STRIX Z490-E. According to `msinfo32`, the BIOS Version/Date is American Megatrends Inc. 0707, 21/07/2020. There is only a beta driver on the [Asus website](https://rog.asus.com/uk/motherboards/rog-strix/rog-strix-z490-e-gaming-model/helpdesk_bios/)

The network adapter shows

[image]

Comment: Ethernet has been embedded into computing technology since Windows XP (or even before). I do not know of any scheduled task that "permits" Ethernet to work. I suggest getting a USB Ethernet card, install it and disable the on-board card.  See if that works.

Comment: Can you describe the problem in more detail. You say "the ethernet can no longer connect", but what exactly does that mean? Does the link link come on? Does the IP address get assigned? What happens when you try to ping the device on the other end of the ethernet link? Do other wired devices work?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, updated post!

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions It's definitely still connected. You can see how there's no X there and it doesn't say "unplugged" or anything like that. You need to do more troubleshooting. For example, can you ping the gateway? If not, what error do you get?

Comment: I've updated the post @DavidSchwartz. It can't ping the local gateway. Not only that, but the computer won't restart via the start menu... only a hard shut down works to get the internet back up

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions What error does the ping fail with? Or does it just not get a response?

Comment: The ping just times out. And an ipconfig doesn't show anything unexpected @DavidSchwartz

Comment: Questions: (1) For comparison, can you add a screenshot of `ipconfig` when everything works? (2) Does disable/enable of the network adapter help? (3) What is the model of your network adapter and what's its driver? (4) What is your computer model and are you using the latest BIOS?

Comment: I will try disable/enable tomorrow when the issue occurs. I hope I've answered your other questions in the latest update @harrymc

Comment: Have you checked your application and system event logs in event viewer?

Comment: @Meow_ly yes. Nothing obvious comes up. Error messages occur saying how various things can't connect to the DNS , and a few about `The driver detected an internal driver error on \Device\VBoxNetLwf.`

Comment: BIOS: If in your ASUS link you click on "See All Downloads", you can see a non-beta one named Version 1003 from 2020/12/23 .

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions bonus, sorry I forgot to add it to my other one. What about in Event Viewer under Applications & Services > Microsoft > Windows > NetworkProfile > Operational? You might be able to find the exact time that it happens that way

Comment: @Meow_ly I did . Nothing that makes me think anything odd is going on. I did note that the only thing in task scheduler that fired at the same time was `Office Automatic Updates 2.0`

Comment: @harrymc disable/enable didn't let me re-enable. So after disabling, it remained disabled. If I tried to enable, I saw the modal window with "enabling" and then "enabled" but it remained greyed out, with no internet

Comment: @harrymc BIOS updated

Comment: More software update ideas: (1)  [Downloads for Intel® Ethernet Controller I225-V](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/184676/Intel-Ethernet-Controller-I225-V), although this doesn't explain the 8AM effect. (2) What is your router model and which firmware version? If the latest version, you might consider a factory reset.

Comment: Some clues to help you to solve the problem.
**Compare route table** when it's working and when it's not working. You have problems with other network interface, maybe one interface take priority over the legitimate.
**Check if network card is always working** by checking with Wireshark if it's able to send packet (when using ping) or receive packet. If you'r stay able to send correctly the packet through the card, you should consider router problems.
Finally, you can **run Process Monitor tools (sysinternal)** just before problem happening and try to get the event creating this problem

Comment: Apart from my above comment, check in the Task Scheduler to see if some task was after all triggered at that time. I would also run several deep antivirus scans.

Comment: Since updating to the Ethernet Controller, the issue has not occurred... I will give it 2 more days then mark as answer :) + bounty (after you create an answer post) @harrymc

Comment: I wrote up an answer, with my theory for the cause. I hope that this funny problem is now solved, as otherwise it would be very difficult to track it down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the problem has disappeared  after updating from the
Intel page of
[Downloads for Intel® Ethernet Controller I225-V](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/184676/Intel-Ethernet-Controller-I225-V).

This might have been a faulty network driver that tried to "phone home" every
morning, but just managed somehow to disable the internet for this computer.

Comment: 2 days in a row, no issue... if tomorrow morning (GMT) is good then yipee